# Python3: Importing a self-contained git submodule containing subclasses/superclasses into a larger project structure without breaking imports

Tags: python, git, pytest, git-submodules

I have a project structure something like this:

```
project/
  - app
    - __init__.py
    - __main__.py
  - dependencies/
    __init__.py
    - git_submodule/
      - __init__.py
      - somefile.py
      - extends_somefile.py
      - tests/
        - conftest.py
        - test_somefile.py
        - test_extends_somefile.py
```

Within `git_submodule`, I want the structure to be completely self contained, so that I can run `python3 -m pytest tests` from `project/app/dependencies/git_submodule/`. ***Note that there is a superclass and subclass which extends it.***

I also want to have an import statement in `project/app/__main__.py` like:

```
from app.dependencies.git_submodule.extends_somefile import ExtendsSomeFile
```

So that if I navigate to 'project/' and run:

`python3 -m app`

None of the imports break. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with Git itself, and instead to just be about how to do the right importing in the various Python files. Is that correct?

Comment: Nothing to do with Git, correct. I am just using a submodule as an example. A better way to put it is that git_submodule/ is a python package.